# How to give the values for drop down list based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

`<select name = Colour id="Colour" onchange="check(this)">`
   `<option value="Select Colour">Select platform</option>`
   `<option>red</option>`
  `<option>blue</option>`
  `<option>orange</option>`
  `<option>purple</option>`
  `<option>pink</option>`
`</select>`
    `</tr>`

   `<td><label>Building</label></td>`
  `<td><label>factory</label></td>`
 `</tr>`
 `<tr>
<`td>
`<input type="text"  name = "Building" id="Building" >`
`<select id = "mass" style="display:none;">`
  `</select></td>`
 `<td><input type ="text" name ="Factory" id ="Factory">`
 `<select id = "Platforms" style="display:none;"></select></td>`
 `</tr>`

<`/html>`
`

when user click on the value of certain drop down for example red then the value for building and factory changes to drop down from text box  . please help me  to give values to building and factory drop downs.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uoEwCDseMUad4Utf?open=lib%2Fscript.js i g gave complete code in this link

Comment: please help me to find answer for this

Comment: You want to change element type from textbox to select (dropdown) or want update values of building?

Comment: when user clicks on colour drop down for example  red the vale for building and factory changes from text field to drop down  i need to give values to those factory and building  drop downs

Comment: its change to drop down only for two colour one is red and other is orange for remaining it would remain text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are looking to add options to select list dynamically. 
You can do it using javascript.

```js
function check(s){
 var c= s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
 const mass = document.querySelector("#mass");
 const building = document.querySelector("#building");
 
  if(c === "red") {
    mass.style.display = "block";
    building.style.display = "none";
    mass.innerHTML = "<option>option 1</option><option>option 2</option>";
  } else {
    mass.style.display = "none";
    building.style.display = "block";
    mass.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#mass {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="check(this)">
 <option></option>
 <option>red</option>
 <option>yellow</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="building" />
<select id="mass"></option>
```